# Got two methods, with same array, sane formula for conversion array elements. Methods returns different values

Tags: java, arrays

Got two methods, with same array, same formula for conversion array elements. Methods returns different values.

Array size:

```
private static final int SIZE = 10000000;
private static final int h = SIZE/2;
```

First method:
array fill with 1, calulate new values with new formula

```
  private static float[] method1() {
    float arr[] = new float[SIZE];

        //array fill with 1,                                                        
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = 1;
    }


       //calulate new values with new formula                                                              
     for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = (float) (i * Math.sin(0.2f + i / 5) * 
                              Math.cos(0.2f + i / 5) * 
        Math.cos(0.4f + i / 2));

    }
     //return new value
        return arr;
}
```

Second Method:
Devide array in two with same length arr/2,
Calculate result for each separately
Compile back in one

```
 private static float[] method2(){
    float arr[] = new float[SIZE];

    float firstarr[] = new float[h];

    float secondarr[] = new float[h];

    float result[] = new float[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i <arr.length ; i++) {
        arr[i] = 1;
    }
      //Devide array in two with same length arr/2,                                                                            
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, firstarr, 0, h);
    System.arraycopy(arr, h, secondarr, 0, h);


    for (int i = 0; i < firstarr.length; i++) {
        firstarr[i] = (float) (i * Math.sin(0.2f + i / 5) *      
                                   Math.cos(0.2f + i / 5) *      
                                   Math.cos(0.4f + i / 2));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < secondarr.length; i++) {
        secondarr[i] = (float) (i * Math.sin(0.2f + i / 5)                   
                                  * Math.cos(0.2f + i / 5)                   
                                  * Math.cos(0.4f + i / 2));
    }
    //compile back in one                                                                                

    System.arraycopy(firstarr, 0, result, 0, h);
    System.arraycopy(secondarr, 0, result, h, h);

    // return result
    return result;

}
```

Caclulate ammount arrays ellements

```
    private static long amount(float[] arr){
    long result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <arr.length ; i++) {
       result += arr[i];
    }
    return result;
}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(amount(method1()));// ammount for first method: 22527562

    System.out.println(amount(method2())); // ammount for second method: -20047478

}}
```

Result for Method1, and Method2 should be the same.
 Where I Made a mistake? Why return values are different?

Comment: deep debug needed :)

Comment: Maybe your error is here **System.arraycopy(firstarr, 0, result, 0, h);
    System.arraycopy(secondarr, 0, result, h, h);** where you have the h,h, i noticed that you dont have the same pattern elsewhere

Comment: h - size array/2                                                                                 private static final int h = SIZE/2;

Comment: @ProgrammingNewb that part seems correct. `System.arraycopy(src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length)` is the signature of that method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in the second method is, that you have 2 identical loops which produce the same array 2 times. `firstarr equals secondarr`. This becomes clear when printing the final arrays:

Method1:

```
[0.0, 0.17933902, 0.066188335, 0.0992825, -0.57430935, -1.2452058, -1.9591095, -2.2856278, -0.8303678, -0.9341638, -3.0198758, -3.3218634, -5.670701, -6.1432595, -2.9212573, 0.3833428, -0.48418152, -0.51444286, -1.0486217, -1.1068785]
```

Method2:
Both arrays:

```
[0.0, 0.17933902, 0.066188335, 0.0992825, -0.57430935, -1.2452058, -1.9591095, -2.2856278, -0.8303678, -0.9341638]
[0.0, 0.17933902, 0.066188335, 0.0992825, -0.57430935, -1.2452058, -1.9591095, -2.2856278, -0.8303678, -0.9341638]
```

Final array:

```
[0.0, 0.17933902, 0.066188335, 0.0992825, -0.57430935, -1.2452058, -1.9591095, -2.2856278, -0.8303678, -0.9341638, 0.0, 0.17933902, 0.066188335, 0.0992825, -0.57430935, -1.2452058, -1.9591095, -2.2856278, -0.8303678, -0.9341638]
```

This shows you that you have to change the second `for-loop` to use the values starting at `h` and going onward. If you use this `for-loop` for `secondarr`, you will get the same result:

```
int counter = h;
for (int i = 0; i < secondarr.length; i++) {
    secondarr[i] = (float) (counter * Math.sin(0.2f + counter / 5) * Math.cos(0.2f + counter / 5) * Math.cos(0.4f + counter / 2));
    counter++;
}
```

As a little side note, you don't need any of these `for-loops`, because they do nothing to your program:

```
for (int i = 0; i <arr.length ; i++) {
    arr[i] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in loops.
First method loop i from 0 to N. Second method loop twice from i to N/2.

For example:
For N = 4 first method returns you

```
i=0 0.0 
i=1 0.17....
i=2 0.066....
i=3 0.099....
```

But the second:

```
i=0 0.0 
i=1 0.17....
i=0 0.0 
i=1 0.17....
```

So the possible solution is to change second loop like this

```
    for (int i = h; i < SIZE; i++) {
    secondarr[i-h] = (float) (i * Math.sin(0.2f + i / 5)                   
                              * Math.cos(0.2f + i / 5)                   
                              * Math.cos(0.4f + i / 2));
}
```